# Do you capitalize counties in this sentence?

Tags: capitalization

Do you capitalize "counties" in the following sentence. Sebastian and Forrest counties are represented.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I believe this is a duplicate of [In what contexts would I capitalize "city" and "county"?](/questions/112387/in-what-contexts-would-i-capitalize-city-and-county) and you may also find *[…coordination among State and local](/questions/323729)*, *[Should “State” be capitalized on its own?](/q/139941)*, *[Capitalization: 'rivers'](/q/199295)*, and *[Capitalize common noun when it follows a list of proper nouns?](/q/395365/)* useful. This is largely a matter of style, and whether you consider *Counties* part of the name or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes counties should be capitalized.

As explained on [yourdictionary.com](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/10-rules-of-capitalization.html):

> ...continents (South America), countries (Belgium), states
>   (Wisconsin), counties (Prince William County), cities (London) and
>   towns (Lizard Lick) get capitalized.

Comment: Also I'm voting that this should be migrated to ELL!